Find the sub-representations of $F(X, k)$
Assumptions: Let

$G$ be a finite group,
$k$ a field,
$X$ a set on which $G$ acts,
$|X| \geq 2$,
$|X/G|=1$
and $char(k) = 0$.

We denote by

$F (X, k)$ the $k$-algebra of functions of $X$ in $k$

and

$e_x$ the function $e_x(y)=\delta_{xy}$ for $y \in X$.

I want help with the following question:

Question: Find the sub-representations of $F(X, k)$.

We have already proved that:

the family $(e_x)_{x \in X}$ is a basis of $F (X, k)$.
$F (X, k)$ is a representation of $G$ with $g e_x = e_{g x}$.
$\dim_{k} F(X,k)^{G} = | X / G |$
$\chi_{ F(X,k) } (g) = |X^{g}|$ where $X^{g} = \{ x \in X : g x = x \}$
$\exists g \in G : X^{g} = \varnothing$


What kind of description are you hoping for? The setup seems way too general.
